# How can I select two characters in a string?

Tags: r, gsub

I know that maybe is something of very easy to resolve but, looking for various example online, I did not find the right example to resolve my problem.

I have in a data.frame under a column a following phrase:

```
ID
p_IIJSJ;o_OODJ;l_jjjjw;g_jjjdI
p_HHDU;o_WWj;l_WWOJ;g_jjjDI
```

I would like to select two words: the one who start with p_ and the one who start with g_ and eliminate all the rest which is between them.... do you have any suggestion about how make it? I'm trying with `gsub` but with no success at the moment.
Thank you a lot in advance

Answer (score 2):

An approach with `strrsplit`,

```
sapply(strsplit(x, ';'), function(i) paste(grep('p_|g_', i, value = TRUE), collapse = ';'))
#[1] "p_IIJSJ;g_jjjdI"
```

or if the order is always the same (as @Jaap mentions)

```
sapply(strsplit(df$ID,';'), function(x) paste(x[c(1,4)], collapse=';'))
```

Comment: For when the words are always in the same order: `sapply(strsplit(df$ID,';'), function(x) paste(x[c(1,4)], collapse=';'))`

Comment: Thank you I'm receiving this error with both approach

Error in strsplit(df$ID, ";") : non-character argument

Comment: That's because your ID column is a factor. Convert to character and try again

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use package `stringr` which makes it easy:

```
library(stringr)

a <- "p_IIJSJ;o_OODJ;l_jjjjw;g_jjjdI"
b <- "p_HHDU;o_WWj;l_WWOJ;g_jjjDI"

str_extract(string = a, pattern = c("p_[a-zA-Z]+", "g_[a-zA-Z]+"))

# [1] "p_IIJSJ" "g_jjjdI"

str_extract(string = b, pattern = c("p_[a-zA-Z]+", "g_[a-zA-Z]+"))

# [1] "p_HHDU"  "g_jjjDI"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub`

```
sub(";*(p_\\w+).*;*(g_\\w+).*", "\\1;\\2", df1$ID)
#[1] "p_IIJSJ;g_jjjdI" "p_HHDU;g_jjjDI"
```

Or with `gsub`

```
gsub("[^pg]_\\w+;", "", df1$ID)
#[1] "p_IIJSJ;g_jjjdI" "p_HHDU;g_jjjDI"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("p_IIJSJ;o_OODJ;l_jjjjw;g_jjjdI", "p_HHDU;o_WWj;l_WWOJ;g_jjjDI"
)), .Names = "ID", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```